# Ruby Linguistics gem

Tags: ruby, linguistics

I try to convert number to words but I have a problem:

```
>> (91.80).en.numwords
=> "ninety-one point eight"
```

I want it to be "ninety-one point eighty". I use Linguistics gem. Do you know some solution for it (prefer with Linguistics).

Comment: That is how you would pronounce that in English though.

Comment: you mean point >> poit and ninety >> ninete? What about other numbers?

Comment: You would pronounce it as if there were no trailing zeroes

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit hackish, but it works:

```
'91.80'.split('.').map {|i| i.en.numwords}.join(' point ')
=> "ninety-one point eighty"
```

When you put 91.80 as a float, ruby gets rid of the trailing zero, so it needs to be a string to begin with to retain that information.  A better example might have been:

```
'91.83'.split('.').map {|i| i.en.numwords}.join(' point ')
 => "ninety-one point eighty-three"
```

Comment: +1 Was just writing EXACTLY the same code when you answer came up

Comment: IMO what you wrote is not correct answer. 
   number = 91.80
   number.split('.').map {|i| i.en.numwords}.join(' point ')
   => "ninety-one point eight"

Comment: @Sebastian, you have to start with the number represented as a string, otherwise there's no actual difference in memory between how 91.8 and 91.80 are stored. (You literally can't tell them apart.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Linguistics gem with Ruby 1.9 you'll need to patch line 1060 of en.rb

```
# Ruby 1.8 -->  fn = NumberToWordsFunctions[ digits.nitems ]
# Ruby 1.9 removed Array.nitems so we get -->  fn = NumberToWordsFunctions[ digits.count{|x| !x.nil?} ]
fn = NumberToWordsFunctions[ digits.count{|x| !x.nil?} ]
```

We submitted the small patch to the author.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer by myself.

```
def amount_to_words(number)
  unless (number % 1).zero?
    number = number.abs if number < 0
    div = number.div(1)                      
    mod = (number.modulo(1) * 100).round    
    [div.to_s.en.numwords, "point", mod.to_s.en.numwords].join(" ")
  else
    number.en.numwords
  end
end
```

And result:

```
>> amount_to_words(-91.83)
=> "ninety-one point eighty-three"
>> amount_to_words(-91.8)
=> "ninety-one point eighty"
>> amount_to_words(91.8)
=> "ninety-one point eighty"
>> amount_to_words(91.83)
=> "ninety-one point eighty-three"
```

Although, thank you guys. Your idea with to_s was helpful for me.